# Need Mongodb query to fetch the data based on the INBOX where ScrubStatus = SCRUBBING

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "id" : "123",
    "name" : "abc",
    "communication" : {
        "INBOX" : {
            "templateId" : 36786,
            "scheduledTime" : "2023-03-14 11:30:00",
            "ScrubStatus" : "SCRUBBING",
            "error" : "SCRUB_RG_FLAG_YELLOW Scrubbed due to RG Yellow"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to fetch the data based on the INBOX `where ScrubStatus = SCRUBBING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({"communication.INBOX.ScrubStatus":"SCRUBBING"})
```